# SLES12 PHP without buying modules

Tags: linux, php, web-server, apache-2.4, sles

We need to install a SUSE Enterprise Linux 12 Server with PHP and Apache.

I've read about the "Web and Scripting Module" - but we just need the server for testing purpose of a live server. And I don't want to spend money just for testing out bugs on a replicated server.

I didn't found a solution on my own using the magic Google site.

So my question is: Is it possible to install/compile PHP (example 5.5) without buying support and modules?

Second Question: Is it possible to install packages from opensuse to SLES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody exists with this problem, this is the answer I got via technical Support:

*You only get the module and access the other modules, if you have a subscription. But if you don't need Patches, Updates etc. you can use the 60Day Trial and install everything you want and after the 60days the system stays how it is. But if you are a ISV/HSV are something else like this and you need SLES for Developement you can get partner with SLES and obtain SDK Versions of SLES12 for free.*

I got [this link](https://www.partnernetprogram.com/) per e-mail.